# Rotate array elements to the left (move first element to last and re-index)

Tags: php, arrays, rotation, shift

Is it possible to easily 'rotate' an array in PHP?

Like this:
1, 2, 3, 4   ->   2, 3 ,4 ,1

Is there some kind of built-in PHP function for this?

Comment: See [here to rotate right instead of left](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63180377/2943403)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Most of the current answers are correct, but only if you don't care about your indices:

```
$arr = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'qux', 'wibble' => 'wobble');
array_push($arr, array_shift($arr));
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [baz] => qux
    [wibble] => wobble
    [0] => bar
)
```

To preserve your indices you can do something like:

```
$arr = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'qux', 'wibble' => 'wobble');

$keys = array_keys($arr);
$val = $arr[$keys[0]];
unset($arr[$keys[0]]);
$arr[$keys[0]] = $val;

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [baz] => qux
    [wibble] => wobble
    [foo] => bar
)
```

Perhaps someone can do the rotation more succinctly than my four-line method, but this works anyway.

Comment: golfed: `list($k,$v)=each($arr);unset($arr[$k]);$arr[$k]=$v;`. You may have to prepend `reset($arr);`.

Comment: And of course, you'd need to tolerate that [`each()` has been deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php).  If you are golfing, then array destructuring braces are shorter than `list()` and `$arr` would be `$a`.

Answer (score 33):

```
  $numbers = array(1,2,3,4);
  array_push($numbers, array_shift($numbers));
  print_r($numbers);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 1
)
```

Comment: This is fine if you're just using your array like a vector, and the index values are not important. But if you have an associative array that you're trying to rotate, this method wrecks your array keys. See my answer for a way that will preserve them.

Comment: @Cam, you're absolutely right about that, even OP haven't mentioned array index, just values. Your answer is valuable for people who are looking for solution to rotate both parts of array elements.
(+1 for your answer)

Comment: yes, clearly your method was sufficient for the OP, otherwise he wouldn't have accepted it! But yeah, thought I'd add my answer in case anyone had the same problem that I did :)

Comment: to rotate right: `array_unshift($numbers,array_pop($numbers));`

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple and could be done in many ways. Example:

```
$array   = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
$array[] = array_shift( $array );
```

Answer (score 4):

Looping through the array, and `shift`-ing and `push`-ing, may be a common way to rotate an array, however it can often mess up your keys. A more robust method is using a combination of `array_merge` and `array_splice`.

```
/**
 * Rotates an array.
 * 
 * Numerical indexes will be renumbered automatically.
 * Associations will be kept for keys which are strings.
 * 
 * Rotations will always occur similar to shift and push,
 * where the number of items denoted by the distance are
 * removed from the start of the array and are appended.
 * 
 * Negative distances work in reverse, and are similar to
 * pop and unshift instead.
 * 
 * Distance magnitudes greater than the length of the array
 * can be interpreted as rotating an array more than a full
 * rotation. This will be reduced to calculate the remaining
 * rotation after all full rotations.
 * 
 * @param array $array The original array to rotate.
 * Passing a reference may cause the original array to be truncated.
 * @param int $distance The number of elements to move to the end.
 * Distance is automatically interpreted as an integer.
 * @return array The modified array.
 */
function array_rotate($array, $distance = 1) {
    settype($array, 'array');
    $distance %= count($array);
    return array_merge(
        array_splice($array, $distance), // Last elements  - moved to the start
        $array                          //  First elements - appended to the end
    );
}
// Example rotating an array 180°.
$rotated_180 = array_rotate($array, count($array) / 2);
```

Alternatively, if you also find the need to rotate keys so that they match with different values, you can combine `array_keys`, `array_combine`, `array_rotate`, and `array_values`.

```
/**
 * Rotates the keys of an array while keeping values in the same order.
 * 
 * @see array_rotate(); for function arguments and output.
 */
function array_rotate_key($array, $distance = 1) {
    $keys = array_keys((array)$array);
    return array_combine(
        array_rotate($keys, $distance), // Rotated keys
        array_values((array)$array)    //  Values
    );
}
```

Or alternatively rotating the values while keeping the keys in the same order (equivalent to calling the negative distance on the matching `array_rotate_key` function call).

```
/**
 * Rotates the values of an array while keeping keys in the same order.
 * 
 * @see array_rotate(); for function arguments and output.
 */
function array_rotate_value($array, $distance = 1) {
    $values = array_values((array)$array);
    return array_combine(
        array_keys((array)$array),        // Keys
        array_rotate($values, $distance) //  Rotated values
    );
}
```

And finally, if you want to prevent renumbering of numerical indexes.

```
/**
 * Rotates an array while keeping all key and value association.
 * 
 * @see array_rotate(); for function arguments and output.
 */
function array_rotate_assoc($array, $distance = 1) {
    $keys = array_keys((array)$array);
    $values = array_values((array)$array);
    return array_combine(
        array_rotate($keys, $distance),   // Rotated keys
        array_rotate($values, $distance) //  Rotated values
    );
}
```

It could be beneficial to perform some benchmark tests, however, I expect that a small handful of rotations per request wouldn't affect performance noticeably regardless of which method is used.

It should also be possible to rotate an array by using a custom sorting function, but it would most likely be overly complicated. i.e. `usort`.

Answer (score 3):

A method to maintain keys and rotate. using the same concept as array_push(array, array_shift(array)), instead we will use array_merge of 2 array_slices

`$x = array("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, 'd' => 4);`

To move the First element to the end

`array_merge(array_slice($x, 1, NULL, true), array_slice($x, 0, 1, true)
//'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4, 'a'=>1`

To move the last element to the front

`array_merge(array_slice($x, count($x) -1, 1, true), array_slice($x, 0,
//'d'=>4, 'a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3`

Answer (score 2):

you can use this function:

```
    function arr_rotate(&$array,$rotate_count) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $rotate_count; $i++) {
            array_push($array, array_shift($array));
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
    $xarr = array('1','2','3','4','5');
    arr_rotate($xarr, 2);
    print_r($xarr);
```

result:

```
 Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 )
```

Comment: Nice succinct function, but I feel it can be improved slightly by ensuring you're not looping through more times than the array has elements. For example `arr_rotate($xarr, count($xarr));` will have the results in the same order. Adding the line `$rotate_count %= count($array);` will ensure that the maximum number of iterations is always less than the number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

There's a task about array rotation on Hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-left-rotation/problem.

And proposed solution with `array_push` and `array_shift` will work for all test cases except the last one, which fails due to timeout. So, `array_push` and `array_shift` will give you not the fastest solution.

Here's the faster approach:

```
function leftRotation(array $array, $n) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
       $value = array[$i]; unset(array[$i]); array[] = $value;
   }
   return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$daynamesArray = array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");
array_push($daynamesArray, array_shift($daynamesArray)); //shift by one
array_push($daynamesArray, array_shift($daynamesArray)); //shift by two
print_r($daynamesArray);
```

The output starts at "Wednesday":

```
Array ( [0] => Wednesday [1] => Thursday [2] => Friday [3] => Saturday [4] => Sunday [5] => Monday [6] => Tuesday
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, here is a function I did myself, where $A is the array and $K the number of times you want to rotate the array:

```
function solution($A, $K) {

  for($i = 0; $i < $K; $i++): //we cycle $K
    $arrayTemp = $A;
    for($j = 0; $j < count($arrayTemp); $j++): // we cycle the array
       if($j == count($arrayTemp) - 1) $A[0] = $arrayTemp[$j]; // we check for the last position
       else $A[$j + 1] = $arrayTemp[$j]; // all but last position
    endfor;
  endfor;
 return $A;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to swap the elements. Algorithm may look like -

```
 for i = 0 to arrayLength - 1
    swap( array[i], array[i+1] )     // Now array[i] has array[i+1] value and 
                                     // array[i+1] has array[i] value.
```

Comment: @Dylan - If you want to write one for yourself, can implement the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Check the documentation for [`array_shift`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and its related functions for some tools you can use to write one.  There might even be an `array_rotate` function implemented in the comments of that page.

It's also worth reading through the array functions listed on the left-hand sidebar to get a full understanding of what array functions are available in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to rotate an array (zero-indexed array) to any position you want:

```
function rotateArray($inputArray, $rotateIndex) {
  if(isset($inputArray[$rotateIndex])) {
    $startSlice = array_slice($inputArray, 0, $rotateIndex);
    $endSlice = array_slice($inputArray, $rotateIndex);
    return array_merge($endSlice, $startSlice);
  }
  return $inputArray;
}

$testArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$testRotates = [3, 5, 0, 101, -5];

foreach($testRotates as $rotateIndex) {
  print_r(rotateArray($testArray, $rotateIndex));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the core solution: (**Shift even if shiftBy is greater than array length**)

```
function rotate($array, $shiftBy)
{
    $res = [];
    $c   = count($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $n       = ($i + $shiftBy) % $c; // mod will take care of positions if rotates
        $res[$n] = $array[$i];
    }
    ksort($res);

    return $res;
}
```

Burn this, you will get it.

Answer (score -1):

Not too dissimilar to the first snippet in ShaunCockerill's answer, I also endorse not making iterated functions calls to perform the rotation.  In fact, I'll recommend using early `return`s to optimize performance and reduce the total number of function calls needed.

The following snippet is the "move left" version of the "move right" version that [I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72677124/2943403).  In my demo, there is a single, static input array and the `foreach()` loop merely changes the desired amount of rotation (0 to 9).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PJpv7))

```
function shiftPop(array $indexedArray, int $shiftPopsCount): array
{
    $count = count($indexedArray);
    if ($count < 2) {
        return $indexedArray;
    }
    $remainder = $shiftPopsCount % $count;
    if (!$remainder) {
        return $indexedArray;
    }
    return array_merge(
        array_splice($indexedArray, $remainder),
        $indexedArray
    );
}

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
foreach (range(0, 9) as $moves) {
    var_export(shiftPop($array, $moves));
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

The first `if` block in my snippet is not engaged by my demo because my array always has 4 elements.  The second `if` block is engaged, when `$moves` is `0`, `4`, and `8` -- in these cases, the input is identical to the desired output, so calling `array_merge()` and `array_splice()` is pointless.

Comment: So this answer was dv'ed for demonstrating and explaining the approach with the lowest time complexity on the page? Sure, that makes sense on a knowledge sharing site.