# Change the order of an array to match hours of day

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has all of the hours of the day listed, 0-23 like this:

```
[0] = 0  [1] = 1 [2] = 2 .... etc
```

Then I used date('G') to find the current hour, for example, 17.

What I want to do is reorder my array so that it starts with the next hour, 18, and then 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2.. etc

What is the best way to do this?  I am feeding this array to a chart that is showing data over the time and having it in this order would really make things easier.

Comment: You splice it at that hour, then move it to the front.

Comment: You are trying to **rotate** an array. That's how it's called. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601707/php-rotate-an-array

Comment: What do you need the initial array for? Find the current hour, then generate the final array you need directly. `$result = array_merge(range($currentHour, 23), $currentHour ? range(0, $currentHour - 1) : array())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function rearrangeHours(&$hours, $hour_key){
  $beforeNow = array_slice($hours,0,$hour_key+1);
  $afterNow = array_slice($hours,$hour_key+1);
  return $hours = array_merge($afterNow, $beforeNow);
}
```

Then you can just do

```
$hours = range(0,23);
rearrangeHours($hours, 15);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23);

for($i = 0; $i < date("G"); $i++)
    array_push($array, array_shift($array));

print_r($array);
```

Assuming `date("G")` is 14, the result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 17
    [4] => 18
    [5] => 19
    [6] => 20
    [7] => 21
    [8] => 22
    [9] => 23
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 1
    [12] => 2
    [13] => 3
    [14] => 4
    [15] => 5
    [16] => 6
    [17] => 7
    [18] => 8
    [19] => 9
    [20] => 10
    [21] => 11
    [22] => 12
    [23] => 13
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice solution with `InfiniteIterator` and `LimitIterator`.
You don't need to change the array. You can work directly with the iterator.

```
$array = range(0, 23);

$start = date("G") + 1;
$count = 24;

$infinate = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
$limit = new LimitIterator($infinate, $start, $count);
```

Then you can use `$limit` like an array.

```
foreach ($limit as $value) {
    print($value . PHP_EOL);
}
```