# Take the two last element from array and deplace in begin of that array

Tags: php, arrays, element, move

I have a array

```
Array ( [0] => elem0 [1] => elem1 [2] => elem2 [3] => elem3 [4] => elem4 )
```

I want take the two last element from array and deplace in begin of that array.

To obtain :

```
Array ( [0] => elem3 [1] => elem4 [2] => elem0 [3] => elem1 [4] => elem2 )
```

in PHP.

Edit

I found :

```
$pkeys= Array ( [0] => elem0 [1] => elem1 [2] => elem2 [3] => elem3 [4] => elem4 );
$output = array_slice($pkeys, -2, 2);
array_splice($pkeys, -2, 2);
$pkeys=array_merge($output,$pkeys);   
print_r ($pkeys);
```

result :

```
 Array ( [0] => elem3 [1] => elem4 [2] => elem0 [3] => elem1 [4] => elem2 )
```

It's OK!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: 'rotate' an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601707/php-rotate-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and [`array_unshift()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php).

Example:

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$last_element = array_pop($stack);
array_unshift($stack, $last_element);
print_r($stack);
```

PHP has many [array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). Take the time to browse them.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of solution can do this , here is one possibility :

```
array_unshift($yourArray,$yourArray[count($yourArray)-2],$yourArray[count($yourArray)-1]);

array_pop($yourArray);

array_pop($yourArray);
```