# PHP Sort weekend array of objects by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an weekend array like :-

```
array (
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[72]
          public 'id' => string '103' 
          public 'day' => string 'monday' (length=6)
          public 'time_from' => string '12:30am' (length=7)
          public 'time_to' => string '12:30am' (length=7)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[71]
          public 'id' => string '104' (length=3)
          public 'day' => string 'tuesday' (length=7)
          public 'time_from' => string '12:00am' (length=7)
          public 'time_to' => string '1:00am' (length=6)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[70]
          public 'id' => string '105' (length=3)
          public 'day' => string 'wednesday' (length=9)
          public 'time_from' => string '12:00pm' (length=7)
          public 'time_to' => string '12:30pm' (length=7)
      3 => 
        object(stdClass)[69]
          public 'id' => string '106' (length=3)
          public 'day' => string 'thursday' (length=8)
          public 'time_from' => string '2:00pm' (length=6)
          public 'time_to' => string '7:00pm' (length=6)
      4 => 
        object(stdClass)[68]
          public 'id' => string '107' (length=3)
          public 'day' => string 'friday' (length=6)
          public 'time_from' => string '12:00am' (length=7)
          public 'time_to' => string '12:30am' (length=7)
      5 => 
        object(stdClass)[67]
          public 'id' => string '108' (length=3)
          public 'day' => string 'saturday' (length=8)
          public 'time_from' => string '12:00am' (length=7)
          public 'time_to' => string '12:30am' (length=7)
      6 => 
        object(stdClass)[67]
          public 'id' => string '108' (length=3)
          public 'day' => string 'sunday' (length=8)
          public 'time_from' => string '12:00am' (length=7)
          public 'time_to' => string '12:30am' (length=7)
    );
```

I want to sort this array by a day like a way: 
suppose today is thursday then the key of thursday if comes first. and then next come Firday,Saterday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday, Wednesday. for ex:-

IF today is Thursday then array will sort like:-

```
array (
          3 => 
            object(stdClass)[69]
              public 'id' => string '106' (length=3)
              public 'day' => string 'thursday' (length=8)
              public 'time_from' => string '2:00pm' (length=6)
              public 'time_to' => string '7:00pm' (length=6)
          4 => 
            object(stdClass)[68]
              public 'id' => string '107' (length=3)
              public 'day' => string 'friday' (length=6)
              public 'time_from' => string '12:00am' (length=7)
              public 'time_to' => string '12:30am' (length=7)
          5 => 
            object(stdClass)[67]
              public 'id' => string '108' (length=3)
              public 'day' => string 'saturday' (length=8)
              public 'time_from' => string '12:00am' (length=7)
              public 'time_to' => string '12:30am' (length=7)
          6 => 
            object(stdClass)[67]
              public 'id' => string '108' (length=3)
              public 'day' => string 'sunday' (length=8)
              public 'time_from' => string '12:00am' (length=7)
              public 'time_to' => string '12:30am' (length=7)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[72]
              public 'id' => string '103' 
              public 'day' => string 'monday' (length=6)
              public 'time_from' => string '12:30am' (length=7)
              public 'time_to' => string '12:30am' (length=7)
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[71]
              public 'id' => string '104' (length=3)
              public 'day' => string 'tuesday' (length=7)
              public 'time_from' => string '12:00am' (length=7)
              public 'time_to' => string '1:00am' (length=6)
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[70]
              public 'id' => string '105' (length=3)
              public 'day' => string 'wednesday' (length=9)
              public 'time_from' => string '12:00pm' (length=7)
              public 'time_to' => string '12:30pm' (length=7)
        );
```

How can i do this type of sorting with array of objects ?

Comment: Take reference of array rotate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601707/php-rotate-an-array

Comment: where are you getting this information? this doesnt seem like array but does seem like an object fetched from somekind of API

Comment: Its a array of object..its copied from var_dump on server so its look like this. @SiimKallari

Comment: @GiteshPurbia is it always in ascending day of week order?

Comment: yes order is in same format..but it will changed according to current day. @zazu

Comment: `sort this array by a day like a way` Love the rhyming (even if I can't work out what you mean)!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
function byDaySort($array)
{
    $dayNo = date('N') - 1;
    if($dayNo == 0)
        return $array;
    elseif($dayNo == 6)
        return array_reverse($array);
    else
        return array_merge(array_slice($array, $dayNo), array_slice($array, 0, 6 - $dayNo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired results, you may use the following function:

```
function rotateArray($arr, $firstDay) {
    $firstElement = reset($arr);
    while($firstElement->day != $firstDay) {
        array_push($arr, array_shift($arr));
        $firstElement = reset($arr);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

You may use it like:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(rotateArray($arr, 'thursday'));
echo "</pre>";
```

---

Disclaimer: You should also check for the existence of the value of the `$firstDay` in the array of `$arr` to avoid an infinite loop :)

Answer (score 0):

This will make it possible,

```
uasort($your_array, function ($a, $b){
    return strtotime($a->day) - strtotime($b->day);
});
```

**Note**: It will preserve keys, if you want keys in ascending order starting with zero, replace [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) with [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

**Explanation**: Why this thing works?

Below is output of `date('d-m-Y',strtotime(day));` as on `18-06-2015 (thursday)`

```
string '22-06-2015' // monday
string '23-06-2015' // tuesday
string '24-06-2015' // wednesday
string '18-06-2015' // thursday
string '19-06-2015' // friday
string '20-06-2015' // satuday
string '21-06-2015' // sunday
```

Observing the above [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will produce the upcoming dates based on the day given.

That means yesterday was `wednesday` on `17-06-2015`, but when `wednesday` is given to make a `date`, it produces the upcoming `wednesday's` date.

If you dump the same tomorrow on `19-06-2015`, you will get output like below,

```
string '22-06-2015' // monday
string '23-06-2015' // tuesday
string '24-06-2015' // wednesday
string '25-06-2015' // thursday   <-- This date changed
string '19-06-2015' // friday
string '20-06-2015' // satuday
string '21-06-2015' // sunday
```

So, basically, that's what we want.

Using this with `uasort()` makes it work as we want.