# Right rotation on array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array for example

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

From this `$a`, how to take last one and set it first like `[5,1,2,3,4]`
And how do I take last two arrays to make it like `[4,5,1,2,3]`

Comment: This looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601707/php-rotate-an-array

Answer (score 6):

You can combine using `array_pop()`, which *pops* the last element of the array out, and `array_unshift()` to push it to the front of the array. You can create a simple function for this,

```php
function array_pop_unshift($array) {
    array_unshift($array, array_pop($array));
    return $array;
}
```

Then use it as

```php
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
$new = array_pop_unshift($a);
print_r($new); // [5,1,2,3,4]
```

To continue shifting it, just call the function again until you're done, for instance through a `for` loop,

```php
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $new = array_pop_unshift($a);
}
print_r($new); // [4,5,1,2,3]
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/CoJZZ

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the cost of several `array_unshift` and `array_pop`, you can build a generator that plays with the array internal pointer.
If you really need a result array, use `iterator_to_array()` to create it:

```
$a = range(1,5);

function rotate(&$array, $step = 1) {
    $length = count($array);
    
    end($array);
    
    while ($step--)
        prev($array);
    
    while ($length--) {
        next($array);
        if (key($array) === null)
            reset($array);
            
        yield current($array);
    }
}

print_r(iterator_to_array(rotate($a, 2))); // [4,5,1,2,3]
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/dZX69)

Note that the `rotate()` generator uses a reference to avoid the array copy but doesn't modify the orginal array: it only moves the array pointer n times (where n is the array length) from the choosen position. When the array pointer is out of the array (`key()` returns `null`) the array pointer is reseted. In other words it stays efficient even with a large array and many rotations (what I have called "step" in the code).

Answer (score 1):

`to take last one and set it first`  This is known as **right rotation.**

And
`$k` is the number of units the shifting should be. `$a` is the array.

```
for($x=0; $x < $k; $x++){

    //remove last element
    $last = array_pop($a);

    //push last element to the beginning
    array_unshift($a, $last);

}
```

`array_pop()` pops and returns the value of the last element of array, shortening the array by one element.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

`array_unshift()`  prepends passed elements to the front of the array
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

You could create a function that takes two arguments `$k`(number of rotations), `$a` (the array) and returns the array after performing right rotation `$k` times.

```
function rotateRight($a, $k){
    for($x=0; $x < $k; $x++){
       //remove last element
       $last = array_pop($a);
       //push last element to the beginning
       array_unshift($a, $last);
    }
    return $a;
}
```

And then call it accordingly.

***Example:***

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5]; 

$a_one_shift = rotateRight($a, 1);
//  [5,1,2,3,4]; 

$a_two_shift = rotateRight($a_one_shift, 1);
// [4,5,1,2,3];
```

Or you could pass 2 to directly get the array after two right rotations.

```
$a_new = rotateRight($a, 2);
// [4,5,1,2,3];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing right rotation, not left. Anyway, here are functions for doing both of them. They are probably not the most efficient but they are short in code and pretty self-explanatory:

```
<?php
    function rotateLeft($array, $times) {
        for($i=0; $i<$times; $i++){
            $array[] = array_shift($array);
        }
        return $array;
    }
    
    function rotateRight($array, $times) {
        for($i=0; $i<$times; $i++){
            array_unshift($array, array_pop($array));
        }
        return $array;
    }
    
    $a = [1,2,3,4,5]; 
    $a = rotateRight($a, 1);
    print_r($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making iterated calls of `array_pop()` and `array_unshift()`, use an efficient, elegant approach that makes fewer function calls and has the lowest possible time complexity.  Using early returns prevents making needless function calls for the same result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QdIUh))

```
function popUnshift(array $indexedArray, int $popShiftsCount): array
{
    $count = count($indexedArray);
    if ($count < 2) {
        return $indexedArray; // array cannot be rotated
    }
    $remainder = $popShiftsCount % $count;
    if (!$remainder) {
        return $indexedArray; // sought rotation is the original order
    }
    return array_merge(
        array_splice($indexedArray, -$remainder),
        $indexedArray
    );
}
```

Disclosure: This answer was built on the CodeReview page ([Codility cyclic rotation solution in PHP](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/277425/141885)) where I offered this snippet in my review.

Answer (score 0):

//$A input array, $K rotation times

```
function solution($A, $K) {
$new = array();
for($j=1;$j<=$K;$j++)
  {
    if(count($new)>0)
        $A = $new;
    for($i=0;$i<count($A);$i++)
      {
        if($i==0)
            $new[$i] = $A[count($A)-1];
        else
            $new[$i] = $A[$i-1];
      }
  }
return $new;}
```