# Reorder elements in array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of elements like this:

```
$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

How can I reorder for example, starting from second element to get `2, 3, 4, 1`; or starting from third element to get `3, 4, 1, 2`?

Comment: `$data = array(2,3,4,1);`? What's the logic behind 2,3,4,1? First element becomes the last element?

Comment: Yes exactly! If I want third element to be first , then second element should be last, so: 3,4,1,2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: 'rotate' an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601707/php-rotate-an-array)

Comment: @NoOorZ24 somehow yes. But that works only for one shifted element. if I want to shift like 2 ,3 elements like for example 4,1,2,3 then it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function to separate the two portions and combine them with `array_merge`:

```
$data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$pos = 2;
$ordered = array_merge(
    array_slice($data, $pos),
    array_slice($data, 0, $pos)
);
// [3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_splice

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4);

$out = array_splice($data, 1, 3);
array_splice($data, 0, 0, $out);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: Even this one can be one of the solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You could just `array_shift()` and then push the shifted value back on to the end of the Array:

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4);
$data[] = array_shift($data);
```