# Sort big array based by matching small array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array-

```
$arraydelivered =
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => pending
            [2] => January
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => pending
            [2] => April
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => pending
            [2] => July
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => pending
            [2] => October
        )

)
```

I want to resort this array dynamically to

```
Array
(
    

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => pending
            [2] => April
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => pending
            [2] => July
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => pending
            [2] => October
        )
[3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => pending
            [2] => January
        )
)
```

I have tried to find out the subarray based on which I know exactly from where to re-sort

```
foreach ($arraydelivered as $keyD => $valueD) {
                                        if($valueD[0] == $cycle){
                                            print_r($valueD);                                    
                                        }    
                                    }
```

This has given me the output -

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => pending [2] => April )
```

Now I want to use this sub-array as the identifier to resort to the main array. Basically this sub-array will be the resort starting point for the big array.

Comment: What is the criteria of your sort? The original array is chronological but I don't understand why you want to have April in the first position. Do you want the next comming month as first? It's a kind of rotation that you want? If it's the case, I would start of with something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/49000563/653182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solve array

```
$keyD1=0;
if(!empty($arraydelivered)){
     foreach ($arraydelivered as $keyD => $valueD) {
             if($valueD[0] == $cycle){
                 $keyD1= $keyD;
               }    

       }
    $outputsec = array_slice($arraydelivered, $keyD1);
    $outputfirst = array_slice($arraydelivered, -4, $keyD1);
    $finalarray= array_merge($outputsec,$outputfirst);
    $arraydelivered=$finalarray;
```